# Connect SDF model to ROS

Tags: sdformat

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello, since I'm a newbie in ROS and Gazebo I'm having trouble to find some tutorial or someone who could explain how to connect a robot SDF model to ROS so that I could acquire sensor data. Is there any tutorial or something that could give me a hint or some plugin which can connect a SDF model to ROS like a URDF model? Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/15762/connect-sdf-model-to-ros/) by [sirsomething](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3124/sirsomething/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-04-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello, there are a few resources that can be useful for you:

- `gazebo_ros_pkg` contains a set of ROS packages to communicate Gazebo and your ROS code. I recommend to read the [wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/gazebo_ros_pkgs) to get a high level overview.
- More specifically, take a look at the "[Using a URDF in Gazebo](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_urdf&cat=connect_ros)" and [the follow-up tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_gzplugins), where you can learn how to load a plugin (`libgazebo_ros_camera.so`) that will publish images via a ROS topic and how to visualize them in `rviz`.
- Additionally, you can take a look at the [Gazebo intermediate guided tutorials](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?cat=guided_i&tut=guided_i1). It's composed by six tutorials where the process of customizing a model in Gazebo is explained. The [tutorial number #6](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?cat=guided_i&tut=guided_i6) contains instructions for receiving ROS messages and modify your simulation (in this case, spinning a Velodyne sensor).

---

Originally posted by [Carlos Agüero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/280/carlos-ag%C3%BCero/) with karma: 626 on 2017-04-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1